# Python: seleccionar el valor más alto siempre que la diferencia sea mayor que 2

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Tengo que hacer una cosa usando Python y no sé si estoy haciendo mal algo o qué. Entiendo que una sentencia IF debería servir, pero no sé como definir las condiciones dado que me da error todo el rato. Vamos allá, a ver si me podéis ayudar. Gracias de antemano.

Tengo un DF con muchas columnas (+250). Cada fila es un usuario. Hay 3 columnas que me dicen la probabilidad de que un usuario sea joven, sea un adulto, o sea una persona mayor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se ha acordado que definiremos si cada usuario es joven, adulto o mayor tomando la columna con un valor más alto. Condición: debe haber 2 puntos o más de diferencia con respecto a la siguiente columna más alta. Si la diferencia es menor a 2, el usuario quedará "indefinido". Por poner un ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como veis, el primer usuario queda indefinido dado que no hay una diferencia mayor a 2 entre "puntos jóvenes" y "puntos mayores". El tercero, en cambio, es mayor dado que la columna con el valor más alto es "puntos mayores" y la diferencia es igual o mayor a 2.

Había pensado que algo así funcionaria, pero me da error:

```
def edad(q):
    if (q["puntos_jovenes"]-q["puntos_adultos"])>1 & (q["puntos_jovenes"]-q["puntos_mayores"])>1:
        return "joven"
    elif (q["puntos_adultos"]-q["puntos_jovenes"])>1 & (q["puntos_adultos"]-q["puntos_mayores"])>1:
        return "adulto"
    elif (q["puntos_mayores"]-q["puntos_jovenes"])>1 & (q["puntos_mayores"]-q["puntos_adultos"])>1:
        return "mayor"
    else:
        return "indefinido"

df["edad"]=df.apply(edad,axis=1)
```

Me devuelve este error:

```
TypeError: ("unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'int' and 'float'", 'occurred at index 0')
```

¿Alguien me puede lanzar una ayuda?

Muchas gracias.

Un saludo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vale, he conseguido solucionarlo. El problema estaba en el booleano &, tal y como rezaba el error.

Lo he podido solucionar cambiando el & por un "and". De modo que así no da error:

```
def edad(q):
    if (q["puntos_jovenes"]-q["puntos_adultos"])>1 and (q["puntos_jovenes"]-q["puntos_mayores"])>1:
        return "joven"
    elif (q["puntos_adultos"]-q["puntos_jovenes"])>1 and (q["puntos_adultos"]-q["puntos_mayores"])>1:
        return "adulto"
    elif (q["puntos_mayores"]-q["puntos_jovenes"])>1 and (q["puntos_mayores"]-q["puntos_adultos"])>1:
        return "mayor"
    else:
        return "indefinido"

df["edad"]=df.apply(edad,axis=1)
```

Aunque si alguien considera que el código puede mejorarse, estoy abierto a sugerencias :)

Un saludo!

Comment: Me alegro que hayas encontrado la solución! Por favor, marca esta respuesta como aceptada para que le puede servir a otra persona con tu mismo problema

Comment: No puedo aceptar mi respuesta todavía. Tengo que esperar 2 días!

Answer (score 3):

Aquí tienes otra idea. No es que el código sea más corto o más legible, pero es más genérico, más fácil de adaptar a otras situaciones.

La idea se basa en tomar el parámetro que te llega `q` y convertirlo a una lista de tuplas usando `q.items()`. Esta lista corresponde a una fila de tu dataframe. El primer elemento de la tupla es el nombre de la columna y el segundo elemento su valor. Así por ejemplo, para la primera fila sería:

```
[('puntos_jovenes', 12.5), ('puntos_adultos', 8.0), ('puntos_mayores', 11.0)]
```

Esta lista la ordenamos de mayor a menor según el valor del segundo campo de cada tupla (para ello usamos `sorted()` y su parámetro `key`). De modo que quedaría así:

```
[('puntos_jovenes', 12.5),  ('puntos_mayores', 11.0), ('puntos_adultos', 8.0),]
```

El primer elemento de esta lista (al ser el de mayor valor numérico) ya nos dice si es un joven, adulto o mayor (en este ejempl, joven). Y restándole el segundo elemento ya sabemos si está o no dentro del margen de tolerancia deseado (en este caso no lo estaría al ser la diferencia menor de 2).

Si está dentro de ese margen, sacar el elemento `[0]` de la primera tupla nos dará una cadena (`"puntos_jovenes"` en este caso) que ya podría ser directamente el valor a retornar, si te sirviese así. Si quieres obligar a que el valor sea en cambio `"Joven"` puedes traducir estas cadenas con ayuda de un diccionario.

Aunque la explicación es un poco larga, el código es breve:

```
# Diccionario opcional para elegir con qué palabra representar cada edad,
# según el nombre de la columna que tenga el mayor valor
traduccion = {
    "puntos_jovenes": "Joven",
    "puntos_adultos": "Adulto",
    "puntos_mayores": "Mayor"
}

def edad(q):
  ordenados = sorted(q.items(), key=lambda t: t[1], reverse=True)
  if ordenados[0][1] - ordenados[1][1] >= 2:
    return traduccion[ordenados[0][0]]  # O directamente return ordenados[0][0]
  return "Indefinido"

df["edad"] = df.apply(edad,axis=1)
```

El resultado sale:

```
   puntos_jovenes  puntos_adultos  puntos_mayores        edad
0            12.5               8            11.0  Indefinido
1            10.5               7            11.5  Indefinido
2             3.5              16            18.0       Mayor
3            10.5               8             4.0       Joven
4             9.0               7             9.0  Indefinido
5            20.0               4             1.5       Joven
6             3.0              16            17.0  Indefinido
```

Por cierto que no sale lo mismo que usando tu solución, porque creo que no estás aplicando bien la condición de tolerancia. La primera fila debe salir "Indefinido", puesto que la distancia entre "joven" y "mayor" es sólo 1.5 que no llega a 2. En cambio tu solución lo clasifica como "joven" (no sé por qué miras que la diferencia sea menor de 1).

Comment: Oh, me parece una solución preciosa, la verdad. Estoy revisando y tienes razón, debería estar >=2 y en lugar de eso está >1. Arreglado. Por cierto, mirando tu solución (que es la que me quedaré), me da este error: 

TypeError: ("'<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'", 'occurred at index 0')

Y no entiendo el motivo, la verdad...

Comment: Respecto al error. Asegúrate de que todas las columnas que estás recibiendo en `q` contienen datos numéricos. Parece que estás recibiendo alguna que contiene una cadena (quizás es que lo estás probando sobre un `df` al que ya habías añadido la columna `"edad"`, que contiene cadenas?).

Comment: Para asegurarte de que no usas otras columnas que puedan dar problemas, sino solo aquellas que están mencionadas en el diccionario `traduccion`, puedes hacer `q[traduccion].items()`, en lugar de `q.items()`.

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo que veas esta publicación muy interesante [`Cuando debería querer usar alguna vez apply en mi código`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code).

Te propongo una solución alternativa, rápida y eficiente:

**Datos de ejemplo**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'puntos_jovenes':[10,11.4,2,5,12,1,4,5.3,7,1],
                   'puntos_adultos':[8,3,7,9,12,4.2,13,9,2,8],
                   'puntos_mayores':[6,3,7,9,5,4,7,10.5,9,11],
                   'otra columna':list(range(2,12))})
```

---

```
diferencia_min = 1
cols = ['puntos_jovenes','puntos_adultos','puntos_mayores']
no_indef = (df[cols].diff(axis = 1)
                    .abs()
                    .iloc[:,-len(cols)+1:]
                    .gt(diferencia_min)
                    .all(axis = 1))
```

---

```
df['Clasificación'] = (df[cols].idxmax(axis = 1)
                               .str.split('_').str[-1]
                               .where(no_indef,'Indefinido'))
print(df)
   puntos_jovenes  puntos_adultos  puntos_mayores  otra columna Clasificación
0            10.0             8.0             6.0           2.0       jovenes
1            11.4             3.0             3.0           3.0    Indefinido
2             2.0             7.0             7.0           4.0    Indefinido
3             5.0             9.0             9.0           5.0    Indefinido
4            12.0            12.0             5.0           6.0    Indefinido
5             1.0             4.2             4.0           7.0    Indefinido
6             4.0            13.0             7.0           8.0       adultos
7             5.3             9.0            10.5           9.0       mayores
8             7.0             2.0             9.0          10.0       mayores
9             1.0             8.0            11.0          11.0       mayores
```

Comment: Boh! Muchas gracias. La publicación que me has enviado es brutal y tu propuesta es más eficiente... La aplicaré. Muchas gracias!